# Add shared row headers in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, rowheader

I haven't been able to find a way to add a shared row header across multiple subplots, as in the figure below. I don't want to use the xlabel of any plot, both because I need the label and because they don't align in the center of the row. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

[image: Grid-Layout]

Answer (score 0):

Is this six different subplots? Maybe see Text in matplotlib helps you. http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html
Consider this is not title but a text at an arbitrary place.